# One component in every view but with different className

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

So, I have a progress bar for my application that I have to put it in every other component with different class name to change the color and show the progress of the process.

```
        <ol>
          <li className="complete" data-step="1">
          </li>
          <li className="active" data-step="2">
          </li>
          <li data-step="3">
          </li>
        </ol>
```

Is there a more proper way to prevent copying the bar in every component and just change the class names based on the component it is in?

Comment: just make it parametrized - component and pass props - render conditionally what you need

Answer (score 1):

You can simply make conditional rendering

Example:

```
    <ol>
      <li className={condition ? "active" : "complete"} data-step="1">
      </li>
      <li className={condition ? "active" : "complete"} data-step="2">
      </li>
      <li data-step="3">
      </li>
    </ol>
```

Comment: thank you but there must be three list elements because there is 3 different phases in the process. there are 2 class names "active" and "complete". for example the first phase is "active" and then when the I finish the first phase the second phase will be "active" and the first phase is "complete" and so on..

Comment: @Gazzar I updated my answer. If you have only two classes to choose from you can do it like that.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
const completedStep = 2; // 1, 2, 3 (0 == nothing is completed)
const steps = ['Step 1', 'Step 2', 'Step 3']; // can be whole component, not just a string

return (
   <ol>
     {steps.map((step, index) => {
        return (
           let className;

           if (index < completedStep) {
              className = 'completed';
           } else if (index === completedStep) {
              className = 'active';
           } else {
              className = '';
           }

           <li
             key={index}
             data-step={index + 1}
             className={className}
           >
              {step}  
           </li>
        );
     })}
   </ol>
);
```

The parameters above can be passed down as props to the component.